Attempting to GetMailTips with Outlook Redemption via python win32com fails for a mess of winhttp issues
Essentially using the basic example code for "GetMailTips" ripped straight from https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMailTips%20.htm , but am unable to get a connection. I strongly suspect an auth issue given the Exchange server is in the cloud (O365). I'm guessing this auth is not supported? Why am I receiving the 401 HTTP ERROR when calling GetSharedMailbox in Redemption? would suggest the auth required isnt supported.
import win32com.client
win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Redemption.RDOSession")
session.SkipAutodiscoverLookupInAD = True
session.Logon()    
adrentry = session.AddressBook.ResolveName("name@name.com")
mailtips = adrentry.GetMailTips()
#dir(mailtips)
print(mailtips.OutOfOfficeMessage)


com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Redemption.RDOMailTips', 'Error in WinHttpReceiveResponse: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT\r\nError in WinHttpSendRequest(eCentral.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED\r\nError in WinHttpSendRequest(autodiscover.eCentral.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT\r\nHTTP error 401 from https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\r\nServer response:\r\n\r\nError in WinHttpQueryHeaders: ERROR_WINHTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND\r\nExpected HTTP_STATUS_REDIRECT, received 403\r\nError in WinHttpSendRequest(eCentral.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED\r\nError in WinHttpSendRequest(autodiscover.eCentral.mail.onmicrosoft.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml): ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT\r\nHTTP error 401 from https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\r\nServer response:\r\n\r\nHTTP error 401 from https://outlook.office365.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\r\nServer response:\r\n\r\nHTTP error 401 from https://outlook.office365.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml\r\nServer response:\r\n', None, 0, -2147418113), None)


The error means Redemption does not have credentials to connect to the server. If it was running inside the outlook.exe address space (e.g. from a COM/VSTO addin or Outlook VBA), it could share credentials used by Outlook, but outside of the outlook.exe address space, there isn't much it can do.

Is there any way to pass the token/credential from outlook into Redemption? Or alternatively, is it possible to run Redemption from inside outlook.exe?

You can try to create RDOSession inside the Outlook address space using Application.CreateObject - just make sure you do that ahead of time, so that Redemption can intercept Outlook credentials.

I will try that next.
I shifted gears to extracting the token from my outook session and requesting getmailtips through the graph api using the requests python module.
